# How to extract 1000 tweets using Python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I’m trying to extract tweets based on the country name but the code always retrieves small amounts of tweets (about 23, 50 and 70, not more than that). Does anyone know how to retrieve tweets around (1000-5000)?

```
# this is not my real credentials 
Consume:
CONSUMER_KEY    = ‘xxx’
CONSUMER_SECRET = ‘ttt’

# Access:
ACCESS_TOKEN  = ‘rffg’
ACCESS_SECRET = ‘mmvvvt’

import tweepy
import csv

# get authorization
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# get tweets from country
place = api.geo_search(query="Saudi Arabia", granularity="country" ,since= '10')
place_id = place[0].id

# print tweets and save to csv file
with open('tweets.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvFile:
    tweetWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    tweets = api.search(q='place:%s' % place_id, count=100, since='1')
    count = 0
    for tweet in tweets:
        count += 1
        # tweet.id = unique id for tweet, text = text, place.name = where it was posted, created_at = UTC time
        tweetData = [tweet.id, tweet.user.name, tweet.text, tweet.place.name, tweet.created_at]
        tweetWriter.writerow(tweetData)

    print(count)
```

Comment: Maybe reading the API instead of copying code, the search method that you're already using should be enough: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.search

Comment: @BtcSources Can you explain more please?

Comment: Where did those `since` parameters come from?